# How can I copy HTML files without Pelican parsing it?

Tags: pelican

I would like to copy some HTML files without Pelicans parse it. On my file system, I have those files in a folder called `html5`. It should be on `{SITE}/html5`.

### Try 1

I've tried adding it to `EXTRA_PATH_METADATA = {'../html5': {'path': 'html5'}}`. But this does not copy the folder to the output.

### Try 2

I've tried to add `STATIC_PATHS = ['images', '../html5']`. This gave me

```
CRITICAL: Error: `/home/moose/GitHub/MartinThoma.github.io/html5/polynom-interpolation.htm` and `/home/moose/GitHub/MartinThoma.github.io/output/../html5/polynom-interpolation.htm` are the same file
```

### Try 3

Adding the `html5` folder directly to `content` gave me the error:

```
ERROR: Skipping html5/regression/regression.htm: could not find information about 'NameError: date'
ERROR: Skipping html5/regression/README.md: could not find information about 'NameError: title'
```

Answer (score 2):

> CRITICAL: Error:
>   `/home/moose/GitHub/MartinThoma.github.io/html5/polynom-interpolation.htm`
>   and
>   `/home/moose/GitHub/MartinThoma.github.io/output/../html5/polynom-interpolation.htm`
>   are the same file

rename one of the file "polynom-interpolation" as something else, two files having the same html filename after pelican generates the output is causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

With

```
STATIC_PATHS = ['images', 'html5']
```

in `pelicanconf.py`, the following happens

```
PELICAN
|-- html5
|   |-- README.md
|-- pelicanconf.py
|-- output
|   |-- html5
|   |   |-- README.md
```

Also: Do not use relative paths pointing "upwards" (`..`). This can and will mess things up.

---

For clarification:

**Try 1**

`EXTRA_PATH_METADATA` does not contain copy instructions by itself.
It can specify where to place a file to copy, but only if the file is to be copied.
The latter information can be specified, for example, in `STATIC_PATHS`.

**Try 2**

This is actually the way to go. `STATIC_PATHS` is a list of files (relative to the pelican project root) which will copied to the output folder.
This means the given relative path will be used to get the files' contents **and** will also be the target file path relative to output for copying.

```
SITE/path/to/file => SITE/output/path/to/file
```

This behavior can be adapted using `EXTRA_PATH_METADATA`.
For example, the list item `'res/htaccess': {'path': '.htaccess'}` has the effect of rewriting the path of the htaccess file from `output/res/htaccess` to `output/.htaccess`.

I can not completely explain why this error occurs.
Considering what I wrote above, the `..` in your path instructs pelican to write the file to `SITE/output/../html5 == SITE/html5`. But as you read from `SITE/../html5` which is in the parent directory of SITE they should not be the **same** file. I can imagine that this is a restriction which prevents you to write outside the output directory. Or you had another copy of html5 in `SITE/html5`.

Maybe your *Try 2* contains *Try 1*, but even that does not perfectly explain why exactly this paths are contained in your error message.

*Bottom line: Be careful when you reference files outside your SITE directory.*

**Try 3**

Obviously this approach does not work.
This way the resources are tried to be understood as article **source** files, which simply can not work.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem today - I had:

```
STATIC_PATHS = [
    'images', 'slides'
]
```

And I wanted to put some HTML and Markdown files to the **slides** directory so users could see them in a raw form. Unfortunately `make html` returned:

> ERROR: Skipping slides/index.html: could not find information about 'NameError: date'
>   DEBUG: Read file slides/systemd.md -> Article
>   ERROR: Skipping slides/systemd.md: could not find information about 'NameError: title'

So after digging deep into pelican codebase I found, that I should also put **slides** directory into **ARTICLE_EXCLUDES**:

```
ARTICLE_EXCLUDES = ['slides']
```

And now it works like a charm.